# Theming react app typescript using MUI version 5

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am trying theme my app using ThemeProvider using MUI version 5.

The React App is using typescript.

```
import { styled, createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';

const themeOptions: ThemeOptions = {
 palette: {
  primary: {
    main: '#5d4037',
    light: '#8b6b61',
    dark: '#321911',
    contrastText: '#ffffff',
  },
  secondary: {
    main: '#c2185b',
    light: '#fa5788',
    dark: '#8c0032',
  },
  background: {
    default: '#c4c9c9',
  },
 }
};

const mdTheme = createTheme(themeOptions);
```

then using theme

```
return (
<ThemeProvider theme={mdTheme}>
```

But it doesnt seems to work.

I get the error

> .ThemeOptions' is not assignable to parameter of type 'import("../node_modules/@mui/material/styles/createTheme").ThemeOptions'.
> Types of property 'mixins' are incompatible.
> Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'MixinsOptions | undefined'.
> Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'MixinsOptions'.  TS2345

Can somebody help?

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

My problem came from using the wrong import :

```
import { Theme, ThemeOptions } from '@mui/material';
```

not

```
import { Theme, ThemeOptions } from '@mui/system';
```